# dhtmlx grid.render_table in java not working

Tags: java, dhtmlx

I'm setting up a dhtmlx grid for loading data using grid.render_table method in java, no rendering is done, I'm new in this

I've tried to implement the PHP 'contact_manager' demo that comes with dhtmlx in java, but grid.render_table does not populate the grid

```
try (PrintWriter out = response.getWriter()) 
        {   
            InitialContext ctx = new InitialContext();
            DataSource ds = (DataSource) ctx.lookup("jdbc/PsFlowWeb");
            conn = ds.getConnection(username, password);

            GridConnector gc = new GridConnector(conn);
            gc.enable_log("temp.log", false);
            LogManager.getInstance().log("any text here");
                        gc.render_table("TCiudades","csCodigoCiudad","csCodigoCiudad,csDescripcionCiudad,csTipoRiesgo");

        }
        catch (Throwable e) { e.printStackTrace(); }
```

I expect the grid be populated with data from server obtained by using grid.render_table method

Answer (score 0):

Could you please, check your log file and the response coming from your data request.